# Getting the column name of a postgres check constraint from information_schema

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I can get the constraint name, the table name and the check_clause of the check constraints on a table using this query:

```
SELECT tc.constraint_type, tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, cc.check_clause
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
JOIN information_schema.check_constraints cc ON cc.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name 
WHERE tc.table_name = $1 and tc.constraint_type = 'CHECK'
```

From information_schema.constraint_column_usage I can get the columns where a PRIMARY or UNIQUE constraint applies but not a CHECK constraint:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage  where table_name = $1
```

This eventually worked following suggestion below:

```
SELECT
ccu.table_schema,
ccu.table_name,
ccu.constraint_name,
ccu.column_name,
cc.check_clause
FROM information_schema.constraint_column_usage ccu
JOIN information_schema.check_constraints cc ON ccu.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
WHERE ccu.constraint_name IN
(
   SELECT
   constraint_name
   FROM information_schema.check_constraints
)
AND ccu.table_name = $1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`CHECK` constraints can exist on domains as well as tables. To get those that are on table columns only do:

```
SELECT
    table_schema,
    table_name,
    column_name,
    constraint_name
FROM
    information_schema.constraint_column_usage
WHERE
    constraint_name IN (
        SELECT
            constraint_name
        FROM
            information_schema.check_constraints);
```

The sub select will find all the `CHECK` constraints in the database and the `constraint_name IN` will filter to only those that are a column constraint.

**UPDATE**

An alternative is to use the system catalogs directly:

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT
        conname,
        conrelid,
        unnest(conkey) AS col_id
    FROM
        pg_catalog.pg_constraint
    WHERE
        contype = 'c'
        AND conrelid > 0
)
SELECT
    conrelid::regclass AS table_name,
    conname,
    attname
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_attribute
    JOIN c ON c.col_id = attnum
        AND conrelid = attrelid;
```

What the above does is restrict the constraint type(`contype`) to `'c'` for `CHECK` and then to only those `CHECK` constraints that exist on table `conrelid > 0` in the CTE(`WITH`) and then joins the `unnest`ed array of columns(`conkey`) to the column information in `pg_catalog.pg_attribute` to get the column names.. The `conrelid::regclass` turns the `conrelid` `oid` value into a table name.

See [pg_constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html) for more information.

Comment: the first query returns the PRIMARY KEY and the UNIQUE constraints but not the CHECK constraints. The second query returns the check but does not give the column name.

Comment: 1) The first query works as expected here. Do your tables have `UNIQUE` and `PK` constraints that have the same names as `CHECK` constraints?  2) That is going to mean expanding `conkey` to the table columns. I will get to that when I have more time.

Comment: See **UPDATE** to system catalog query.

Comment: thanks. I used your information_schema example to give me what I wanted.